# Trying to access array offset on value of type null {"userId":1447,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):

Tags: php, sql, laravel, backend, e-commerce

I have been using a ecommerce website written in laravel.The code was written 1-2 years ago. Whenever I try to use credit card payment. I get the error  saying trying to access array offset on value of type null also I get refID not found

> ''' local.ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
> (View:
> /var/www/html/resources/views/frontend/checkout/checkoutAjax.blade.php)
> {"userId":1447,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/frontend/checkout/checkoutAjax.blade.php)
>
> at /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/901a80e27c928eb0dd7d906efe14a3377b93b333.php:43,
> ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at
> /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/901a80e27c928eb0dd7d906efe14a3377b93b333.php:43)

I am getting the log file as follow

> [2022-02-04 18:00:58] local.ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/frontend/checkout/checkoutAjax.blade.php)
>
> {"userId":1447,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/frontend/checkout/checkoutAjax.blade.php)
>
> at /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/901a80e27c928eb0dd7d906efe14a3377b93b333.php:43,
> ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/901a80e27c928eb0dd7d906efe14a3377b93b333.php:43)
>
> [stacktrace]
>
> #55 {main} "}  [2022-02-04 18:04:24] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'refID' cannot be null
> (SQL: insert into `tbl_payments` (`refID`, `SessionID`, `action`,
> `status`, `amount`, `payment_method`, `gateway`, `request`,
> `response`, `remark`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?,
> GetOrderStatus, ?, ?, 1, Pay By Card (Debit/Credit/Prepaid), GetOrderStatusEN600000001066220, GetOrderStatus30,
> >  12:19:10">423559XXXXXX22888000DECLINED8000BINOD
> > GAUTAMVISAfalsefalse81false81falseVISAYMTY0Mzk3NzEwODA2MzAwMDAwMDA=Y3331978@encrypted@1@5856994B87058004CE9568FFEB0A8C94B63E406E841368C4PurchaseORDER_REQ_82625959520351238140780.0080.000.000.00Nepalese RupeeNPR04/02/2022
> > 12:19:10GeneralDECLINEDTransaction ResultMTY0Mzk3NzEwODA2MzAwMDAwMDA=Nabil
> > Bank
> > Ltdsarasmart.com1.0050524CE9568FFEB0A8C94B63E406E841368C4eng,
> > 2022-02-04 18:04:24, 2022-02-04 18:04:24)) {"exception":"[object]
> > (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]:
> > Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'refID' cannot be null
> > (SQL: insert into `tbl_payments` (`refID`, `SessionID`, `action`,
> > `status`, `amount`, `payment_method`, `gateway`, `request`,
> > `response`, `remark`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?,
> > GetOrderStatus, ?, ?, 1, Pay By Card (Debit/Credit/Prepaid),  version='1.0'
> > encoding='UTF-8'?>GetOrderStatusEN600000001066220, GetOrderStatus30,
> > <Message date="04/02/2022
> > 12:19:10">423559XXXXXX22888000DECLINED8000BINOD
> > GAUTAMVISAfalsefalse81false81falseVISAYMTY0Mzk3NzEwODA2MzAwMDAwMDA=Y3331978@encrypted@1@5856994B87058004CE9568FFEB0A8C94B63E406E841368C4PurchaseORDER_REQ_82625959520351238140780.0080.000.000.00Nepalese RupeeNPR04/02/2022
> > 12:19:10GeneralDECLINEDTransaction ResultMTY0Mzk3NzEwODA2MlkwMDAwMDA=Nabil
> > Bank
> > Ltdwebsitename.com1.0050524CE9568FFEB0A8C94B63E406E8413456eng,
> > 2022-02-04 18:04:24, 2022-02-04 18:04:24)) at
> > /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664,
> > PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
> > violation: 1048 Column 'refID' cannot be null at
> > /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458)

```
'''
```

I am getting refID cannot be null. Can anyone help me please. Please let me know if any file is required to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: please check isset condition before use the variable`isset($yourdatacheck)`

Comment: Where is the code?